# 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' on random points in Hololens application

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens, .net-4.6

For building a Hololens application I use Unity experimental .NET version 4.6 in combination with .NET version 4.6 DLL's. The DLL's have references to eachother.

After building to the Hololens and running, the application throws on random points a System.IO.FileNotFoundException.

Full exception:
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll
Could not load file or assembly 'DataStorage, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.

DataStorage is a DLL which the application has a reference to and gets used in different classes than where the exception throws.

More exceptions like this happen like not finding System.Core or System.Regex

Is it a fault in the DLL or is it because of the experimental .NET version in Unity?